# Connect polyLines by marker, rather than coordinates, in R Leaflet Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a shiny app, using r leaflet, that is a map of the world with markers indicating scientific researchers.  the markers are circle markers, and they show the researcher name and the text "clink for details" when the mouse hovers over the marker.  when the marker is clicked on a pop up appears with the researcher name, institution , and field of study, with the researcher name being a link to a url for their home page.  the markers are clustered by proximity, given that many researchers will work from the same institution. the location on the map of each researcher marker is defined by the longitude and latitude values of the institution.  in addition there is a split layout with a panel showing a list of institutions and fields of study as checkboxes that can be toggled to filter the markers according to those criteria.  finally, in order to link collaborators geographically, I have created polylines to connect researchers who share the same "collaboration" value.

Unfortunately, I can only figure out how to connect poylines by coordinates, and in my structure the coordinates correspond to the institution, not the individual researcher.  so as it is right now the lines connect the institutions.  how can I connect the researcher markers specifically? Is that even possible using these tools?

In short: I would like to know if it is possible to distinguish between markers that share the same coordinates so that when the cluster is expanded a specific marker from that cluster can be connected to a separate marker outside that cluster by a polyline?

Here are the variable (column) names from the .csv file that is imported as mapData:
`lat,   long,   institution,    department, researcher, researcherLink, sphere, status, collaboration` 
"sphere" corresponds to the field of study mentioned above.

Here is the working code (which I like, save for the lines terminating on the institution coordinates rather than the researcher markers):

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(dplyr)

# Prepare your data (example data)
mapData <- read.csv(fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM", "mapData.csv")
lineData1 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 1) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)
lineData2 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 2) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)
lineData3 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 3) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)
lineData4 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 4) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)
lineData5 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 5) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)
lineData6 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 6) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)
lineData7 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 7) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)
lineData8 <- subset(mapData,
                    collaboration == 8) %>%
  select(lat, long, collaboration)

# Calculate the bounding box of regions with circle markers
circleBounds <- with(mapData, {
  bounds <- list(
    lng = range(long),
    lat = range(lat)
  )
  bounds
})

# Create an initial map with specified view
map <- leaflet(data = mapData) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  fitBounds(lng1 = circleBounds$lng[1], lat1 = circleBounds$lat[1],
            lng2 = circleBounds$lng[2], lat2 = circleBounds$lat[2])

    
# Create a Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
        #map {
          height: 100vh !important;
        }
        .custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content {
          width: 1600px !important;
        }
        .leaflet-label {
          display: none;
        }
        .leaflet-marker-icon:hover .leaflet-label {
          display: block;
        }
        .leaflet-tooltip-pane .leaflet-tooltip {
          max-width: 250px;
        }
      ")
    )
  ),
  splitLayout(
    cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
    leafletOutput("map"),
    wellPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("institution", "Institutions", choices = unique(mapData$institution), selected = unique(mapData$institution)),
      checkboxGroupInput("sphere", "Fields of Study", choices = unique(mapData$sphere), selected = unique(mapData$sphere))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Render the initial map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    map
  })
  
  # Create a reactive expression for the filtered data
  filteredData <- reactive({
    mapDataFiltered <- mapData
    
    # Filter data based on selected institutions
    if (length(input$institution) > 0) {
      mapDataFiltered <- mapDataFiltered[mapDataFiltered$institution %in% input$institution, ]
    }
    
    # Filter data based on selected fields of study
    if (length(input$sphere) > 0) {
      mapDataFiltered <- mapDataFiltered[mapDataFiltered$sphere %in% input$sphere, ]
    }
    
    mapDataFiltered
  })
  
  # Update markers based on selected institutions and fields of study
  observe({
    data <- filteredData()
    
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData1, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData2, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData3, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData4, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData5, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData6, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData7, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      addPolylines(data = lineData8, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat) %>%
      clearMarkerClusters() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
        data = data,
        radius = 20,
        color = "red",
        stroke = FALSE,
        fillOpacity = 0.8,
        label = lapply(data$researcher, function(x) HTML(paste0(htmlEscape(x), "<br>Click for details"))),
        popup = ~paste(
          "Researcher:", ifelse(!is.na(researcherLink), paste0("<a href='", researcherLink, "' target='_blank'>", researcher, "</a>"), researcher), "<br>",
          "Institution:", institution, "<br>",
          "Field of Study:", sphere
        ),
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
          spiderfyDistanceMultiplier = 1.5
        ),
        labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = FALSE, direction = "auto", style = list("font-weight" = "bold", "white-space" = "nowrap"))
      )
  })
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```